# Add comment based on searched string in vim

Tags: vim

I want to add a comment at the beginning of the line based on a search string in vim. I think I'm close, but this replaces the searched string.

```
:%s/.*someString/^#/g
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use & to reference previously searched for text when replacing.

For example,

```
:%s/.*someString/#&/g
```

Would comment out the line.  I'm confused about what exactly you're asking though.

Comment: +1 Cool, `&` is neat! @AdamB Don't forget to accept the answer since it solves your problem!

Comment: Haha I have no idea what I did before I discovered &.  It's the kind of feature that really should be better documented.  Glad to help :)

Comment: @NolenRoyalty I won’t be surprised if you appeared to discover this by trying to replace with `&`. For me it would be more convenient if `&` substitution was removed in favor of already working `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
:%s/^\(.*someString\)/#\1/g
```

Comment: I am still confused about exactly what this question is asking for but I'm pretty sure this solution is better than mine.

Comment: I didn't know about the & before - it's very useful. Thanks!

Comment: @NolenRoyalty He wants to put # at the beginning of any line that has the search string.

Comment: @jimw You misplaced the comment :) I agree - very useful trick, which obviously I did not know about :)

Comment: Oops, so I did. Hopefully Nolen will notice my appreciation ;)

Answer (score 0):

This not-so-elegant command might work:

```
g/.somestring/s/.somestring/otherstring/g|:normal 0i{This Line Has Changed}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Did you mean it really works. In that case remove the 'might part'